# Appending to a slice with enough capacity using value receiver

Tags: pointers, go, append, slice

can someone help me understand what happens here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func appendString(slice []string, newString string) {
    slice = append(slice, newString)
}

func main() {
    slice := make([]string, 0, 1)
    appendString(slice, "a")
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

I know about the slice header and the need to use a pointer receiver. But here, as the underlying array has enough capacity I would expect append to work anyways (just adding the new value to the underlying array and the original [copied] header working as expected)

What is wrong with my assumptions?

Comment: `append` always returns a new slice header, because the length field has to change. You are only thinking about the underlying *array* which doesn't need to be reallocated here. But the slice always changes.

Comment: @Peter Not always, only if more than 0 elements are appended.

Comment: @Peter that was exactly my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's add a final print statement to see the result:

```
slice := make([]string, 0, 1)
fmt.Println(cap(slice))
appendString(slice, "a")
fmt.Println(slice)
```

And the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5jNaWH_ja8G)):

```
1
[]
```

Which is correct. One could expect the output to be:

```
1
[a]
```

The reason why this is not the case is because even though a new backing array will not be allocated, the slice header in the `slice` variable inside `main()` is **not changed**, it will still hold `length = 0`. Only the slice header stored in the `slice` local variable inside `appendString()` (the parameter) is changed, but this variable is independent from main's `slice`.

If you were to reslice main's `slice`, you will see that the backing array does contain the new string:

```
slice := make([]string, 0, 1)
fmt.Println(cap(slice))
appendString(slice, "a")
fmt.Println(slice)

slice = slice[:1]
fmt.Println(slice)
```

Now output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wniphnszM5Y)):

```
1
[]
[a]
```

This is why the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) has to return the new slice: because even if no new backing array is needed, the slice header (which contains the length) will have to be changed (increased) if more than 0 elements are appended.

This is why `appendString()` should also return the new slice:

```
func appendString(slice []string, newString string) []string {
    slice = append(slice, newString)
    return slice
}
```

Or short:

```
func appendString(slice []string, newString string) []string {
    return append(slice, newString)
}
```

Which you have to reassign where you use it:

```
slice := make([]string, 0, 1)
fmt.Println(cap(slice))
slice = appendString(slice, "a")
fmt.Println(slice)
```

And then you get the expected outcome right away (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/67iXz0S219l)):

```
1
[a]
```

Comment: Great answer, I was just considering the backing array and not the length value. Thanks.