# why slice values can sometimes go stale but never map values?

Tags: dictionary, pointers, go, reference, slice

I find that slice map function and channel are frequently mentioned together as *reference types*. However I notice that slices somethings exhibit none reference behavior like they can go stale:

```
   var s []int
   //must update slice value
   s = append(s, ...)
```

or

```
   //must use pointer if we want to expose the change
   func foo(s *[]int) error  
   //or change the function signature to return it like _append_
   func foo(s []int) (r slice, err error)
```

Usually I understand this by keeping the inner components of the slice discriptor implementation in mind: A slice value can be seen as a struct of len, cap and data pointer.

But map values need never bother like

```
   m := make(map[string]int)
   ...
   // don't know how to express with insertion, but you know what i mean.
   m = delete(m, "well")
```

Why? Is a map value just a pointer to the map descriptor? If so why not also make slice this way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Go there are no reference types like you have them in C++. In Go everything is passed by value. When the term "reference type" is used in Go, it means a type that references to the data they ought to represent (via pointers).

Slices are small, struct-like data structures represented by the type [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader):

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

It contains a pointer to the first element of the slice in an underlying array (`SliceHeader.Data` field). This struct is small and is efficient to pass as a value, no need to pass its address (and dereference it to access indirectly any of its fields). The elements of a slice are not stored in the slice header, but in an array outside of the header's memory area. This means modifying a "pointed" element will modify the element of the original slice.

When you append (more than 0) elements to a slice, the `Len` field in the header must change, so the new slice that describes the slice with the additional elements must be a different than the one before the append, that's why you need to assign the return value of the builtin `append()` function. (Other values may also change, but `Len` sure must change.)

Maps are implemented as pointers to the `runtime.hmap` structure:

```
type hmap struct {
    // Note: the format of the hmap is also encoded in cmd/compile/internal/gc/reflect.go.
    // Make sure this stays in sync with the compiler's definition.
    count     int // # live cells == size of map.  Must be first (used by len() builtin)
    flags     uint8
    B         uint8  // log_2 of # of buckets (can hold up to loadFactor * 2^B items)
    noverflow uint16 // approximate number of overflow buckets; see incrnoverflow for details
    hash0     uint32 // hash seed

    buckets    unsafe.Pointer // array of 2^B Buckets. may be nil if count==0.
    oldbuckets unsafe.Pointer // previous bucket array of half the size, non-nil only when growing
    nevacuate  uintptr        // progress counter for evacuation (buckets less than this have been evacuated)

    extra *mapextra // optional fields
}
```

As you can see, this is a lot more complex data structure that a slice header, and is a lot bigger, passing this as value would not be efficient.

Adding / removing elements (key-value pairs) from a map is stored in buckets that are referenced by the fields of this struct, but since maps are handled as pointers under the hood, you do not need to assign the result of such operations.

To be complete, channels are also implemented as pointers, pointing to the `runtime` package's `hchan` type:

```
type hchan struct {
    qcount   uint           // total data in the queue
    dataqsiz uint           // size of the circular queue
    buf      unsafe.Pointer // points to an array of dataqsiz elements
    elemsize uint16
    closed   uint32
    elemtype *_type // element type
    sendx    uint   // send index
    recvx    uint   // receive index
    recvq    waitq  // list of recv waiters
    sendq    waitq  // list of send waiters

    // lock protects all fields in hchan, as well as several
    // fields in sudogs blocked on this channel.
    //
    // Do not change another G's status while holding this lock
    // (in particular, do not ready a G), as this can deadlock
    // with stack shrinking.
    lock mutex
}
```

This is again a "fat" struct and is handled like map values.

**See related questions:**

[slice vs map to be used in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590444/slice-vs-map-to-be-used-in-parameter/47590531#47590531)

[Appending to a slice with enough capacity using value receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009514/appending-to-a-slice-with-enough-capacity-using-value-receiver/53009770#53009770)

[Are golang slices pass by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-pass-by-value/39993797#39993797)

[What do "value semantics’" and "pointer semantics" mean in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264339/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean-in-go/51265000#51265000)

Comment: and one of the most confusing things for beginners about passing a (non-pointer) slice into a function: the function can alter elements within the slice - but cannot change the capacity or length. So appends *may* work - if the slice has capacity - but if not and the slice is reallocated under the covers - this change is lost, as the change happens to the copied slice-header. Solution: pass the slice address.

Comment: @colminator Or return the new slice, just like the builtin `append()` does, and have the caller assign it.

Comment: That is very elaborating thanks @icza. By the way i notice that my question is voted down does that mean my way of thinking or describing is not the usual gopher way and perhaps exhibits influences from other programming language  which is not a good start?

Answer (score 4):

Slice is a paper-thin wrapper over a contiguous chunk of memory and it's often beneficial to reuse that content, partially or in whole (avoid copying the data). Map has none of these characteristics. It's a complex data structure with complex behaviour and you can't reuse its storage (like you do with slices).