# Can I use defer to delete an element of a map?

Tags: dictionary, go, pointers, defer-keyword

```
type Tasks map[int]CustomValue

func (t *Tasks) Put(task MyTask) {
    (*t)[len(*t)] = task
    return len(*t) - 1
}

func (t *Tasks) Get(taskID int) interface{} {
    defer func() {         // Is this OK???
        delete(*t, taskID)
    }()
    return (*t)[jobID].GetValue()
}
```

Here is my code of Go. Basically, I'm using a map to store some "key-value"s. And I have two functions `Put` and `Get`.

After getting the value, I want to delete the element from the map.

Can I simply use the defer mechanism to do so? I don't know if the defer function must be invoked after return.

Comment: If you have multiple goroutines using these functions, you'll need to a mutex to prevent a data-race. The mutex unlock can be placed in a `defer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `defer` may be used to remove an element from the map like you intend to use it.

[Spec: Defer statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)

> ...if the surrounding function returns through an explicit [return statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements), deferred functions are executed *after* any result parameters are set by that return statement but *before* the function returns to its caller.

So `(*t)[jobID].GetValue()` will be evaluated before the deletion in the deferred function happens.

Note however that maps are pointers under the hood (for details see [why slice values can sometimes go stale but never map values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520624/why-slice-values-can-sometimes-go-stale-but-never-map-values/55521138#55521138)), so you should use non-pointer receiver. This also simplifies your code a lot, and will make it more efficient.